# How to validate complex viewmodel in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view model called designvm
and there are two classes .

```
{
    public customer customer {get;set;}
    public student student {get;set;}
}
```

in my viewmodel the fields are like

```
<form>
 <input asp-for="customer.customername" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
 <span asp-validation-for="customer.customername" class="text-danger"></span>

 <input asp-for="student.studentname" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
 <span asp-validation-for="student.studentname" class="text-danger"></span>
</form>
```

My problem is I can't validate because property names are not matching .
In class it's only customername and in view it is customer_customername. How can I validate in the view ?

Comment: Why do you say in view it's `customer_customername`? Above code says `customer.customername`.

Comment: id value is customer_customername

Comment: It doesn't matter, this should work. When you include `asp-for="customer.customername"` this renders default id and name `id="customer_customername" name="customer.customername"` but it still performs validation. Please provide more details. May be the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Daniel Manta how can I submit this form in the asp.net controller?

Comment: I need to submit these two models in the controller via ajax

Comment: that's basic stuff, I'm sure this was asked before and you also can follow a tutorial

Comment: Will you please provide me a link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use server side validation by using data annotation attribute,you just need combine with default `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` in the asp.net core project which contains `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to validate the form.

Model:

```
public class Test
{        
    public customer customer { get; set; }
    public student student { get; set; }

}
public class customer
{
    [Required]
    public string customername { get; set; }
}
public class student
{
    [Required]
    public string studentname { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Test
<form>
    <input asp-for="customer.customername" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
    <span asp-validation-for="customer.customername" class="text-danger"></span>

    <input asp-for="student.studentname" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
    <span asp-validation-for="student.studentname" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="button" id="post" value="Post" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $("#post").click(function () {
            var flag = $("form").valid();  //validate the form valid or not
            if (flag) {
                alert("success");
                //do your stuf...
                //ajax...
            }

        })
    </script>
}
```

_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

If your project does not contain the same js,you could add reference manually in the view like below:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" integrity="sha512-o6XqxgrUsKmchwy9G5VRNWSSxTS4Urr4loO6/0hYdpWmFUfHqGzawGxeQGMDqYzxjY9sbktPbNlkIQJWagVZQg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script>
        $("#post").click(function () {
            var flag = $("form").valid();
            console.log(flag);
            if (flag) {
                alert("sucess");
            }

        })
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

A simple demo about how to pass form to the backend by using ajax:

```
<script>
    $("#post").click(function () {
        var flag = $("form").valid();
        var data = $("form").serialize();
        console.log(data);
        if (flag) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/PostData",
                type: "Post",
                data: data,
                success: function (res) {
                    //...
                }
            })
        }

    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostData(Test model)
{

    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks..One more problem i am facing .That is in my controller I want to map these viewmodel object to actual model .. it is not happening .because property name in view is customer.customername and in actual model is not only customername .

Comment: Besides,I updated my answer and share a simple demo about how to pass model to the backend.

Comment: the model object  is null .

Comment: This Test model is null I am not getting why this is happening. Thanks for the help mate

Comment: So that is why I suggest you post a new thread and share how do you pass the model.You need share your view and js and model design entirely,otherwise we can not find your issue.And in stackoverflow,you need accept answer if the answer resolve your issue,if you have another issue,please post a new thread.Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks . in your case is it coming in the controller ?

Comment: Yes,it works well.Actually,the property name is correct.It should be `customer.customername`.I think you need use `console.log()` to log the data you pass.

Comment: @Rena After your last update, when you click "post" button to run ajax, since the button is in a form it's also posting back the entire page. You need prevent default before making ajax call `$("#post").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`. Otherwise debugger hits both methods `Test` and `PostData` in your controller. Apart from that your code works fine and `Test` model getting data in controller method.